# NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest' with Chrome Browser - Ext JS

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, extjs, xmlhttprequest

I am getting an error on logging out from an application via Chrome browser only.

Chrome browser version 86.0

> Blocked alert('Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on
> 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load
> 'https://host-name/web/base/logout?id=40dee37f-cf1d-40f9-b01d-2a414d446a77&tenant=ABC&isFrameMode=true&_dc=1602665141328':
> Synchronous XHR in page dismissal. See
> https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/4664843055398912 for more
> details.. line: 1. url:
> https://hostname/web/base/abc/app.js?_dc=20161213063112') during
> unload.

Code that is being used to logout from Application :

```
var vRequest = { url: vUrl, async: false },
Ext.Ajax.request(vRequest);
```

Have tried changing the async attribute value from false to true but now the request status is being displayed as canceled in Developer Tools.

Comment: Can Someone check and advice on this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not the ajax call.  The problem is the call is, based on the error your are getting, happening during an event that is no longer allowed, beforeunload, unload, pagehide, visibilitychange... etc

[Here are some alternate ways to return data to the server on logout.](https://web.dev/disallow-synchronous-xhr/)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion....!  
 
I have tried the below workarounds which doesn't works and showing Chrome XHR/fetch request Cancelled in Developer Tools.

1) change the async attribute value to true. 

2) Fetch API and Navigator.sendBeacon APIs

Kindly advice.